# showcase display mode for published app in shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny

I just want to know about showcase mode in shiny application, 
when we run our shiny application in local for the showcase mode we can using command like this

```
setwd('D:/xxxx/')
runApp("aa",display.mode = "showcase")
```

My question is how if we want to show our code (showcase mode) in our application that we want to publish in shinyapps.io

Thank you,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can provide information about your app that Shiny showcase will use by creating a DESCRIPTION file. The file should be written in plain text and contain Title, Author, and DisplayMode fields in [Debian Control File (DCF)](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html) format. You can also include other optional fields, such as AuthorUrl, License, and Tags. The description file of Shiny’s built in 01_hello example is displayed below
You can change title, author name, and your link..

```
Title: Hello Shiny!
Author: RStudio, Inc.
AuthorUrl: http://www.rstudio.com/ 
License: GPL-3
DisplayMode: Showcase
Tags: getting-started
Type: Shiny
```

Shiny will use the DisplayMode field to determine the default display mode for your app. If you set the field to Showcase, Shiny will open your app in showcase mode. If you set it to Normal, Shiny will open your app in Normal mode. Your users can override this default by using the display.mode argument of runApp.

See [Full Documentation](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/display-modes.html)

Comment: This looks almost identical to the earlier answer from @BrianP

Answer (score 5):

Create a text file with no extension.  Name this file: `DESCRIPTION`.  Place the following content and edit as necessary.  The display mode is set for Showcase.

```
Title: Hello Shiny!
Author: RStudio, Inc.
AuthorUrl: http://www.rstudio.com/
License: GPL-3
DisplayMode: Showcase
Tags: getting-started
Type: Shiny
```

Save this file in the same directory as your `server.R` and `ui.R` files.  Deploy as usual.  Here is the reference:  http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/display-modes.html.  Just be sure that you don't have a file type or extension associated with your `DESCRIPTION` file.

Answer (score -1):

This person is asking about shinyapps::deployApp. We can run display.mode using runApp locally with no problem, but the same argument does not work when deploying to shinyapps.

UPDATE: One option on shinyapps.io is to add "?showcase=0" to the URL. It remains difficult to remove the showcase display mode for local, even after a reboot.

Comment: Please don't post "me too" as an answer. Instead, you may star this question as a favorite to be notified of any new answers. Once you have sufficient reputation, [you may also upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) it. Or, to correct an answer, [comment](http://$SITEURL$/privileges/comment).

Comment: I think this was a clarification. The two responses seemed to be non-responsive to the original question.

Comment: Clarifications should be added as comments too.

Comment: but check it out! I did post one possible solution in the response with my update yesterday.