# Upload Shiny App to shinyapps.io in Showcase Mode

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to upload a Shiny App to shinyapps.io in [Showcase mode](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/display-modes.html). According to those directions, one includes a text file named `DESCRIPTION` (no extension) with the following fields (this is from the example linked above:

```
Title: Hello Shiny!
Author: RStudio, Inc.
AuthorUrl: http://www.rstudio.com/
License: GPL-3
DisplayMode: Showcase
Tags: getting-started
Type: Shiny
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26291523/showcase-display-mode-for-published-app-in-shinyapps-io) describes the same process - but, it seems like it doesn't work any longer.

When I try to publish a Shiny App with a `DESCRIPTION` file like the one int he example, the following error is returned:

```
Preparing to deploy application...DONE
Uploading bundle for application: 88219...Error in readDcf(file.path(project, "DESCRIPTION"))[, "Package"] : 
  subscript out of bounds
Calls: <Anonymous> ... suppressMessages -> withCallingHandlers -> <Anonymous> -> unname
Execution halted
```

For what it's worth, I tried excluding different fields from the `DESCRIPTION` file, even trying one with only `DisplayMode: Showcase` included. I also tried saving the file in different editors.

This [Google Groups thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shinyapps-users/xq-p2_nTPAE) seems to suggest this is a bug, but since there doesn't seem to be a question posted about it other than when this worked, I hoped to see if anyone had found or could suggest a fix.

EDIT: I posted an [Issue on the Shiny Apps GitHub page](https://github.com/rstudio/shinyapps/issues/195#issuecomment-195709926).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing the latest version of `packrat` from GitHub (i.e., `devtools::install_github("rstudio/packrat")` did the trick, thanks to [this GitHub Issue suggestion](https://github.com/rstudio/shinyapps/issues/195#issuecomment-195709926). Installing the latest CRAN version (`install.packages("packrat")`) did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I open my shinyapp on the shiny server in [Showcase mode](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/display-modes.html)  using DESCRIPTION file with additional fields that were not described in [documentation](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/display-modes.html) and it works.

```
Package: MyShinyApp
Version: 1.0
Title: Hello Shiny!
Author: RStudio, Inc.
AuthorUrl: http://www.rstudio.com/
License: GPL-3
DisplayMode: Showcase
Tags: getting-started
Type: Shiny
```

Adding fields `Package` and `Version` will resolve this error `ERROR system error 71 (Protocol error) [description=Version field not found in...]`