# R: display mode for single-file shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, single-file, displaymode

When using two files (ui.R and server.R), one can change display mode with:

```
runApp("MyApp", display.mode = "showcase")
```

How can I set display mode to "showcase" for single-file shiny app?

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Display mode can be changed using DESCRIPTION file.

Details answered in this question:
[showcase display mode for published app in shinyapps.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26291523/showcase-display-mode-for-published-app-in-shinyapps-io)

Answer (score 1):

What about now?

```
runApp(display.mode = 'showcase',

  list(
  ui=shinyUI(fluidPage(
    numericInput('n', 'Number of obs', 100),
    plotOutput('plot')
  )), 

  server= shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    output$plot <- renderPlot({ hist(runif(input$n)) })
  })

))
```

Comment: I am not calling runApp() command manually, Shiny Server is. Is there a way how to preset server to run in 'showcase' mode?

Comment: See now if is this what you want